# How to get same shell completion as Arch Linux ISO

Tags: bash, arch-linux, autocomplete

[image]

I noticed this when booting the arch linux ISO:

1. e.g. type `shift` at prompt
2. then press tab
3. auto-completion list pops-up below (inside red rectangle in screenshot)
4. press tab tab
5. use arrow keys to navigate

I installed arch linux a few years ago, I run updates regularly, I installed bash-completion, but I have not got this feature.

What's the name or how do I get this feature or how do I set it up correctly?

Comment: Are you sure it's `bash`? Last time I built an Arch system, the .iso used `zsh`, which was configured with this kind of auto-completion...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Arch ISO uses [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/) and the [grml config](https://grml.org/zsh/). This is [documented on the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Sample_.zshrc_files):

> To get the same setup as the monthly ISO releases (which use Zsh by
>   default), install grml-zsh-config. It includes the many tweaks and
>   advanced optimizations from grml.